# How does one defeat the three small bug minions underground in Level 14?

Tags: vim-adventures

I've already defeated the Big Bug.

I see the hint that the small bugs disguised as cursors are vulnerable to the three words "Charity", "Uganda", and "Bram".

I think I have all keys available, I've tried undoing with the bugs on the three words, I've tried motions which include the three words in their range, I have each of the three words stored in a named register, but I haven't figured out how to defeat the three small bug minions underground in Level 14 of Vim Adventures.

I suspect I should have defeated them before defeating Big Bug, maybe even before finding 'undo'. Is there instead something I should do in the 'lorem' buffer where I found the three cursors (Blue, White, and Pink) at the beginning of the level?

How does one defeat the three small bug minions in Level 14?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I emailed the game's creator. I quote his response below:

> Actually, you already have everything you need. You already know the words that
>   they are vulnerable to, you just have to use them in a command such as / or ?.
>   You have to make sure that they are in the range of the command and that the
>   command actually moves the cursor so that the bugs are within the range.
>
> So if you're using ?Charity for example, you need to be somewhere at the bottom
>   of the text so that the range will be big enough to include the bug (try any
>   one of the three and if it's not the one, try one of the others). In addition,
>   if 'Charity' is not a part of the text due to the use of undo or redo you have
>   to fix that first.
>
> These bugs are exactly like all the other bugs, only their vulnerability isn't
>   written on their back.

I can confirm that this solution worked for me.