# Vim with the c command

Tags: vim-adventures

I'm stuck on the last exercise of the level 14 in Vim-Adventures. According to the following picture, could anyone be able to tell me what I have to do here? Which command do I have to use (`c`,`y`,`a`,`d` or `i`) and how ?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one defeat the three small bug minions underground in Level 14?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/151397/how-does-one-defeat-the-three-small-bug-minions-underground-in-level-14)

Answer (score 1):

Wow -- it looks like you managed to kill the Big Bug before you killed the Mr. White, Mr. Pink / Mr. Red, and Mr. Blue bugs.  Impressive.  Anyway, to kill the little bugs, you search for `Bram`, `Uganda`, and `Charity`, using the `/` and `?` keys.  (This is the meaning of the clue in the `U` puzzle, visible after you do `ctrl-r` there.)

(Thanks much to the [Vim Adventures walk-through on GitHub](https://github.com/pepers/vim-adventures), because I got about halfway through level 14, then got stuck for over a week!  I'd still be banging my head on the keyboard without that walk-through.)

Edit:  I've noticed a similar question, [How does one defeat the three small bug minions underground in Level 14?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/151397/how-does-one-defeat-the-three-small-bug-minions-underground-in-level-14).  I suppose the title of this question could be clearer.